# Range of a rational algebraic function

Tags: functions, quadratics, rational-functions

How do we find the range of an algebraic rational function of the form $(a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1)/(a_2x^2+b_2x+c_2)$ for real values of x?

For instance, take the function f(x) = $(16x^2-12x+9)/(16x^2+12x+9)$ .

Now, one thing which I was able to get was that since both the polynomials have their discriminant $D < 0$, so they must always be positive and since both the polynomials are always positive, the expression must be always greater than $0$. However, I don't know how to go from here. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you allowed to use calculus? If yes, that's pretty direct. If no, I think it can be slightly tricky unless you're very well versed in proving inequalities.

Comment: @CalvinLin Actually this Question is meant to be done without calculus. But I would love to have a calculus based solution of it .

Comment: Note that $d$ is in the range if and only if there is at least one real number $x$ such that $f(x)=d$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $ y = \frac{ 16x^2 - 12 x + 9 } { 16x^2 + 12x + 9 } $.

Since the denominator is non zero, we can multiply by the denominator and shift terms to get

$$ x^2 ( 16y - 16) + x ( 12y + 12 ) + (9y- 9 ) = 0 $$

This is a quadratic equation with real roots, which means that the discriminant is non-negative. Hence,

$$ 0 \leq (12y+12)^2 - (16y-16)(9y-9) = -144 (3-y)(1-3y), $$

so the range is contained within $ [ \frac{1}{3} , 3 ] $.

Note that for this to truly be a quadratic, we require $ 16y - 16 \neq 0$, or that $ y \neq 1$. In this case, we're solving the linear equation $24x = 0 $, which has a solution $x = 0$, so $y=1$ is in the range. Henceforth, let's ignore $ y = 1$ as an edge case.

Conversely, for any $ y \in [ \frac{1}{3} , 3 ] $, we can solve the corresponding quadratic equation since the discriminant is non-negative, to obtain a real $x$. Hence, that $y$ value is in the range.

Hence, the range is exactly $[ \frac{1}{3} , 3 ] $.

---

Note: This works for rational functions where the denominator is a quadratic with no real roots.
It doesn't easily extend to higher degree polynomials.

Comment: Very slick. It $might$ seem that you have only shown that $\forall y\,(y\in [1/3,3]\,).$ But for $any$ $y_0\in [1/3,3]$, the discriminant is $\ge 0$, implying the quadratic equation  in $x$ has a solution $x_0\in \Bbb R$, implying that $y=y_0$ when $x=x_0.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Right, that was what I intended. I edited it for clarity.

Comment: @CalvinLin you assumed that the expression is quadratic therefore $y \neq1$ but you got it in your answer, you must verify it'

Comment: @LalitTolani . In some contexts, including this, it is common to refer to any $Ax^2+Bx+C$ as quadratic in $x$. The logic of the Answer is unaffected  by any of $A,B,C$ being $ 0.$

Comment: @LalitTolani Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited that in.

Answer (score 3):

So you want to know a solution involving calculus, here it is-

We have, $f(x)=\displaystyle\frac{16x^2-12x+9}{16x^2+12x+9}$

Clearly, $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)=1$ $(1)$

Now $\displaystyle f(x)=1-\frac{24x}{16x^2+12x+9}$

Let denominator be equal to $u$

$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=-\frac{(16x^2+12x+9)24-24x(32x+12)}{u^2}$

$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=0$ implies

$16x^2+12x+9-32x^2-12x=0$

$16x^2-9=0$ therefore $f(x)$ has it extremums at $x=\pm \frac{3}{4}$

Now $\displaystyle f(x)=1-\frac{24x}{(4x+3)^2-12x}$

Therefore value of $f(x)$ at extremums $f(0.75)=\frac{1}{3}$ and  $f(-0.75)=3$

Therefore by $(1)$ we can say that these are global maximum and minimum values of $f(x)$ and hence range of $f(x)$ is $\displaystyle \big[\frac{1}{3},3\big]$

Comment: +1. When $x\ne 0$ we can also write $f(x)=1-24/g(x)$ where $g(x)=16x+12+9/x,$ and use some basic algebra to find the range of $g(x).$ Mainly to find $\min \{g(x):x>0\}$ and $\max \{g(x):x<0\}.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet minimum can be found by using A.M. -G.M. , how to look for maximum?